# org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate flushing: could not insert - Spring MVC

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc, rally

I am getting below error while trying to insert data in Oracle.

> rg.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate
>   flushing: could not insert: [RallyDefect]; uncategorized SQLException
>   for SQL [insert into EDS_OPS_RALLY_DEFECTS_DUPLI (LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
>   CLOSED_DATE, CREATION_DATE, DEFECT_ID, DEFECT_NAME, DESCRIPTION,
>   ENVIRONMENT, ITERATION, NOTES, PRIORITY, PROJECT, RELEASE_NAME,
>   RESOLUTION, SEVERITY, STATUS, SUBMITTED_BY, SERIALNO) values (?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [72000]; error
>   code [1461]; ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a
>   LONG column ; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException:
>   ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Couldn't see a solution in various posts.

DAO class

```
public void addRallyDefects(RallyDefect rallyDefect) {

    System.out.println("==inside RallyDaoImpl ==");
    System.out.println("==rallyDefect =="+ rallyDefect.getDefectid());
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(rallyDefect);
    //sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
}
```

Service Implementation

```
String[] defectattributes = { "FormattedID", "Name", "State",
            "Description", "Severity", "Environment", "CreationDate",
            "ClosedDate", "Resolution", "Notes", "Priority",
            "LastUpdateDate", "Release", "Project", "SubmittedBy",
            "Iteration", "Tag" };
    try {
        QueryRequest defects = new QueryRequest("defect");

        defects.setFetch(new Fetch(defectattributes));
        defects.setOrder("FormattedID ASC");
        defects.setPageSize(1);
        defects.setLimit(1000);
        QueryResponse queryResponse = restApi.query(defects);
        if (queryResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
            JsonObject defect = new JsonObject();
            for (JsonElement result : queryResponse.getResults()) {
                defect = result.getAsJsonObject();
                RallyDefect defectrows = new RallyDefect();
                defectrows.setDefectid((defect.get("FormattedID")
                        .getAsString()));
                defectrows.setDefectname((defect.get("Name").getAsString()));
                defectrows.setStatus((defect.get("State").getAsString()));
                if (defect.get("Description").isJsonNull()) {
                    defectrows.setDescription("");
                } else {
                    defectrows.setDescription(html2text((defect.get("Description")
                            .getAsString())));
                }
                if(defect.get("Severity").isJsonNull()){
                    defectrows.setSeverity("");
                }else{
                defectrows.setSeverity((defect.get("Severity").getAsString()));
                }
                if(defect.get("Environment").isJsonNull()){
                    defectrows.setEnvironment("");
                }else{
                defectrows.setEnvironment((defect.get("Environment").getAsString()));
                }
                if(defect.get("CreationDate").isJsonNull()){
                    defectrows.setCreationDate((java.sql.Date)new Date());
                }else{
                defectrows.setCreationDate(convertDate((defect.get("CreationDate").getAsString())));
                }
                if(defect.get("ClosedDate").isJsonNull()){
                    defectrows.setClosedDate(new java.sql.Date(0));
                }else{
                defectrows.setClosedDate(convertDate((defect.get("ClosedDate").getAsString())));
                }
                if(defect.get("Resolution").isJsonNull()){
                    defectrows.setRelease("");
                }else{
                defectrows.setRelease(html2text((defect.get("Resolution").getAsString())));
                }
                if(defect.get("Notes").isJsonNull()){
                    defectrows.setNotes("");
                }else{
                defectrows.setNotes((defect.get("Notes").getAsString()));
                }
                if(defect.get("Priority").isJsonNull()){
                    defectrows.setPriority("");
                }else{
                defectrows.setPriority((defect.get("Priority").getAsString()));
                }
                if(defect.get("LastUpdateDate").isJsonNull()){
                    defectrows.setLastUpdateDate((java.sql.Date)new Date());
                }else{
                defectrows.setLastUpdateDate(convertDate((defect.get("LastUpdateDate").getAsString())));
                }

                if (defect.has("Release") && defect.get("Release").isJsonNull()) {
                    defectrows.setRelease("");
                } else {
                        defectrows.setRelease((defect.get("Release").getAsJsonObject().get("Name").getAsString()));
                    }                   

                if (defect.has("Project") && defect.get("Project").isJsonNull()) {
                    defectrows.setProject("");
                } else {
                        defectrows.setProject((defect.get("Project").getAsJsonObject().get("Name").getAsString()));
                    }                   

                if (defect.has("SubmittedBy") && defect.get("SubmittedBy").isJsonNull()) {
                    defectrows.setSubmittedBy("");
                } else {
                        defectrows.setSubmittedBy((defect.get("SubmittedBy").getAsJsonObject().get("_refObjectName").getAsString()));
                    }               

                if (defect.has("Iteration") && defect.get("Iteration").isJsonNull()) {
                    defectrows.setIteration("");
                } else {
                        defectrows.setIteration((defect.get("Iteration").getAsJsonObject().get("Name").getAsString()));
                    }

                // adding Defects data
                rallyDao.addRallyDefects(defectrows);

                System.out.println("==Before exiting from Serivce == ");
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("The following errors occurred: ");
            for (String err : queryResponse.getErrors()) {
                System.err.println("\t" + err);
            }
        }
    }

    finally {
        // Release all resources
        restApi.close();
    }
}

public static String html2text(String html){
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}

public static String replaceNull(String input) {
    return input == null ? "" : input;
}

public static java.sql.Date convertDate(String datevalue) throws ParseException{

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(datevalue);
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date1.getTime());
    return sqlDate;
} }
```

One important note: I am trying to insert around 300 records. Not sure is this the issue.

Below is my Model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RALLY_DEFECTS")

public class RallyDefect implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "SERIALNO")
    private Integer defectCountNum;

    @Column(name = "DEFECT_ID")
    private String defectid;

    @Column(name="DEFECT_NAME")
    private String defectname;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "SEVERITY")
    private String severity;

    @Column(name = "ENVIRONMENT")
    private String environment;

    @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
    private Date creationDate; 

    @Column(name = "CLOSED_DATE")
    private Date closedDate;

    @Column(name = "RESOLUTION")
    private String resolution;

    @Column(name = "NOTES")
    private String notes;

    @Column(name = "PRIORITY")
    private String priority;

    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATE_DATE")
    private Date LastUpdateDate;

    @Column(name = "RELEASE_NAME")
    private String release;

    @Column(name = "PROJECT")
    private String project;

    @Column(name = "SUBMITTED_BY")
    private String submittedBy;

    @Column(name = "ITERATION")
    private String iteration;
}
```

Table definition

> CREATE TABLE RALLY_DEFECTS
>   (
>     PROJECT           VARCHAR2(3000 BYTE),
>     DEFECT_ID         VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
>     DEFECT_NAME       VARCHAR2(3000 BYTE),
>     DESCRIPTION       VARCHAR2(3900 BYTE),
>     PRIORITY          VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
>     SEVERITY          VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
>     STATUS            VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
>     ENVIRONMENT       VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
>     SUBMITTED_BY      VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
>     OWNER             VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
>     TAGS              VARCHAR2(3000 BYTE),
>     RELEASE_NAME      VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
>     ITERATION         VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE),
>     CREATION_DATE     DATE,
>     CLOSED_DATE       DATE,
>     LAST_UPDATE_DATE  DATE,
>     RESOLUTION        VARCHAR2(3900 BYTE),
>     NOTES             VARCHAR2(3900 BYTE),
>     SERIALNO          NUMBER,
>     LASTUPDATEDATE    DATE,
>     CLOSEDDATE        DATE,
>     CREATIONDATE      DATE,
>     RELEASE           VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
>     SUBMITTEDBY       VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
>   )
>   TABLESPACE OPS_DAT
>   RESULT_CACHE (MODE DEFAULT)
>   PCTUSED    0
>   PCTFREE    10
>   INITRANS   1
>   MAXTRANS   255
>   STORAGE    (
>               INITIAL          64K
>               NEXT             1M
>               MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
>               MINEXTENTS       1
>               MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
>               PCTINCREASE      0
>               BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
>               FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
>               CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
>              )
>   LOGGING 
>   NOCOMPRESS 
>   NOCACHE
>   NOPARALLEL
>   MONITORING;

Comment: No the issue is that you're trying to save a LONG into a column that is not of type LONG. Show your tabledefinition, and show the code of the RallyDefect entity. All the code you posted is irrelevant.

Comment: @ JB added table definition and entity class

Comment: You forgot the `@Temporal` annotation on fields of type Date.

Comment: thanks for the info JB. However it didn't fixed the issue. I am able to insert the data in to table for few records. i didn't faced any issue while inserting 5 or 10 records. I am facing issue only when inserting bulk records more than 50. Any code to display column and record number? to debug more

Comment: I just read the exception again: it complains about the table EDS_OPS_RALLY_DEFECTS_DUPLI, and you posted an entity mapped to the table RALLY_DEFECTS. So it's irrelevant. Post the entity mapped to EDS_OPS_RALLY_DEFECTS_DUPLI.

Comment: @ JB it is not irrelevant, I have two tables one which ends with DUPLI, which is for testing and other is to insert live data, before i run the program every time i will change the table name in Model class

Comment: Does any one has suggestions to  debug or capture which record is failing. Exception details is not clear on which column has issue.